# can't create checkbox widget without tristate property

Tags: flutter

I can't create checkbox widget without tristate propertym this code generate a error:

```
 body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[


            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Lunes'),
                Checkbox(
                  value: monday,
                  onChanged: (bool value){
                    setState(() {
                      monday = value;
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
```

this code works fine:

```
 body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[


            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Lunes'),
                Checkbox(
                  tristate: true,
                  value: monday,
                  onChanged: (bool value){
                    setState(() {
                      monday = value;
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Why i need tristate?

Comment: What error are you facing? You ran and everything is fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

"monday" needs to be non-null (bool). I presume it has not been initialized when defined or in initState(), but you don't appear to have shown that code.